# Complexity of approximating the size of the range of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, computer-science

Given an $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$ with $m \leq n$ and elements from $\{-1,1\}$, let us define:

$$S_M = |\{Mx : x \in \{-1,1\}^n\}.$$

It is NP-hard to compute $S_M$ exactly I believe by applying the reductions from this [cstheory question and answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20277/decide-whether-a-matrixs-kernel-contains-any-non-zero-vector-all-of-whose-entri) to the following decision problem. Is $S_M < 2^n$?

> Is it possible to approximate $S_M$ to within a constant factor in
>   polynomial time? If not, what is the best one can do in polynomial
>   time?

My hunch is that a constant factor approximation cannot be achieved in polynomial time (<strike>unless P = NP</strike> maybe under some complexity theoretic assumption) but it would be very interesting to know how to give even a square root approximation, for example.

[Previously asked at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33676/complexity-of-approximating-the-range-of-a-matrix with no answers/comments.]

Comment: It's not even immediately clear to me that P=NP would imply a positive answer.  Is constant-factor approximation of $S_M$ easily seen to be in NP?  Or is there some other argument for this implication?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies You are right I overstated that part and I was also sloppy with the decision problem I gave before (now fixed).  The decision question "Is $S_M < 2^n$?" is equivalent to asking if there exists a non-zero $\{-2,0,2\}^n$ vector in the kernel of $M$ and it is this problem which is NP-complete.